# What detrimental effect do declined flags have?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, flag-ban

What detrimental effect do declined flags have, and do I have any come-back on those declined flags?

I've just noticed (as I don't normally keep track of these things) that a flag that I raised on a comment a couple of weeks ago was declined... but at the time I raise the flag, it was perfectly valid.

The user in question appeared to not be an English speaker, and had written their comment in a language other than English.  I flagged it as "Not in English"... but the user must have written the comment, submitted it, run the text through a translation service, then updated the comment with the (very rough) English translation.

The result is that I flagged the comment correctly, but now have a declined flag.

How is that going to effect me in the long run?
(I guess not a lot, but I would be interested to know.)

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHamidi - I did try and find similar situations, but they were complaining about *why* they were being rejected, rather than the upshot of being rejected (especially if they felt the rejection was wrong)

Comment: @freefaller, the answer under the duplicate contains an explanation about flag bans and a link to Shog9's original answer on the Overmeta. All the other related questions I could find were closed as a duplicate of that one, so I thought it would be a good idea to also use it here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, fair enough.  I can see that time plays a big part in it... and as I don't flag regularly (and have had two rejections in the last 3 years) I'm guessing I shouldn't really worry!  Thanks for your time